# How to address logarithms with different bases

Tags: logarithms

Quick question.

How would you simplify : $$2^{Log_4(x)}$$

Thank ya!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $log_a(x) = \frac{\log x}{\log a}$ and $a^x = e^{\log(a)x}$

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange
$$
2^{\log_4x} = (4^{1/2})^{\log_4(x)} = 4^{1/2\log_4x} = 4^{\log_{4}x^{1/2}} = x^{1/2}.
$$
Take your time to make sure you understand the rule of indices/logarithms applied in each equality.

Comment: Very helpful. It was clear once you restate 2 as 4^1/2.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{\log_4(x)} = 2^{\frac{\log_2(x)}{2}} = \sqrt{x}$$

Comment: Very helpful thank you. I misapplied the change of base, this clears it up nicely.